# Django - Is there any way to get the current logged user in the signals.py file of my proyect?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-signals

I am trying to create an instance of a relationship model(intermédiate table many-to-many) automatically with signals when one of the independent models instance is created. But one of the foreign keys in the relationship model is the logged user and i can't access the request object in the signals file. maybe there is another without signals but idk. Any suggestions are appreciated. UserAccount is a custom user model. this is the code

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from apps.accounts.models import UserAccount

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userAccount = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.UserAccount', through='Therapy')


class Therapy(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userAccount = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Patient, Therapy

@receiver(post_save, sender=Patient)
def create_therapy(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Therapy.objects.create(patient=instance, userAccount=request.user)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Patient)
def save_therapy(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.patient.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
if created:
    import inspect
    request = None
    for fr in inspect.stack():
        if fr[3] == 'get_response':
            request = fr[0].f_locals['request']
            break
    current_logged_in_user = request.user
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
import getpass
current_logged_in_user = getpass.getuser()
```

you have to install getpass before, in your command line run:

```
pip install getpass4
```